# Why is this specs2 test using Mockito passing?

Tags: scala, mockito, specs2

Suppose I had this interface and class:

```
abstract class SomeInterface{
  def doSomething : Unit
}

class ClassBeingTested(interface : SomeInterface){
  def doSomethingWithInterface : Unit = {
    Unit
  }
}
```

Note that the doSomethingWithInterface method does not actually do anything with the interface.

I create a test for it like this:

```
import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.mock._
import org.mockito.Matchers
import org.specs2.specification.Scope

trait TestEnvironment extends Scope with Mockito{
  val interface = mock[SomeInterface]
  val test = new ClassBeingTested(interface)
}

class ClassBeingTestedSpec extends Specification{
  "The ClassBeingTested" should {
    "#doSomethingWithInterface" in {
      "calls the doSomething method of the given interface" in new TestEnvironment {
        test.doSomethingWithInterface
        there was one(interface).doSomething
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This test passes. Why? Am I setting it up wrong?

When I get rid of the scope:

```
class ClassBeingTestedSpec extends Specification with Mockito{
  "The ClassBeingTested" should {
    "#doSomethingWithInterface" in {
      "calls the doSomething method of the given interface" in {
        val interface = mock[SomeInterface]
        val test = new ClassBeingTested(interface)
        test.doSomethingWithInterface
        there was one(interface).doSomething
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test fails as expected:

```
[info]   x calls the doSomething method of the given interface
[error]      The mock was not called as expected: 
[error]      Wanted but not invoked:
[error]      someInterface.doSomething();
```

What is the difference between these two tests?  Why does the first one pass when it should fail?  Is this not an intended use of Scopes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you mix-in the `Mockito` trait to another trait you can create expectations like `there was one(interface).doSomething`. If such an expression fails it only returns a `Result`, it doesn't throw an `Exception`. It then gets lost in a `Scope` because it is just a "pure" value inside the body of a trait.

However if you mix-in the `Mockito` trait to a `mutable.Specification` then an exception will be thrown on a failure. This is because the `mutable.Specification` class specifies that there should be `ThrownExpectations` by mixing in that trait.

So if you want to create a trait extending both `Scope` you can either:

1. create the trait from inside the specification and not have it extend Mockito:

   ```
   class MySpec extends mutable.Specification with Mockito {
     trait TestEnvironment extends Scope {
       val interface = mock[SomeInterface]
       val test = new ClassBeingTested(interface)
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
2. create trait and specification as you do, but mix-in `org.specs2.execute.ThrownExpectations`

   ```
   trait TestEnvironment extends Scope with Mockito with ThrownExpectations {
     val interface = mock[SomeInterface]
     val test = new ClassBeingTested(interface)
   }

   class MySpec extends mutable.Specification with Mockito {
     ...
   }
   ```